# SwiftUI + ScrollView not able to add views if it's exceed view height

Tags: swift, text, scrollview, swiftui, geometryreader

I am trying to show all the properties of the `Text` component in a single view. Showing `Text` with different styles and fonts. For that I am adding multiple `Text` components in a single view.

To make it possible I am using the `ScrollView` component and adding all `Text` components in it.
At some point, it won't allow me to add one more component in the scrollView and showing different errors each time.

Code:

```
struct TextClass: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                Text("This is suppose to be a really long text that can go on to multiple lines. By default, it could go more than one lines.").padding()

                Text("This is only one line regardless of how long the sentence is")
                    .padding()
                    .lineLimit(1)
                Text("Hello Swift - LargeTitle").font(.largeTitle).padding()
                Text("Hello Swift - Title").font(.title).padding()
                Text("Hello Swift - Headline").font(.headline).padding()
                Text("Hello Swift - SubHeadline").font(.subheadline).padding()
                Text("Hello Swift - body").font(.body).padding()
                Text("Hello Swift- callout").font(.callout).padding()
                Text("Hello Swift- Footnote").font(.footnote).padding()

                Text("Font Weight - Ultralight").fontWeight(.ultraLight).padding()
                Text("Font Weight - Thin").fontWeight(.thin).padding()
    //            Text("Font Weight - light").fontWeight(.light).padding()
    //            Text("Font Weight - Regular").fontWeight(.regular).padding()
            }.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
        }
    }
}

struct TextClass_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextClass()
    }
}
```

It shows error like:

[image]

If I comment line

```
Text("Font Weight - Thin").fontWeight(.thin).padding()
```

the error is gone.

It seems that it only allows me to add 10 `Text` component in this situation If I add more than that it gives me an error.

Is it a bug? is it a common behavior in SwiftUI? What is the benefit of scrollView if it won't allow adding more components?

Comment: It's documented limitation of SwiftUI, just embed your `Text` (or other views) in `Group {}` by 10 (or less) items

Comment: So sad, btw thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Group` as you can't have more than 10 elements inside a view

```
struct TextClass: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    Group {
                            Text("This is suppose to be a really long text that can go on to multiple lines. By default, it could go more than one lines.").padding()
                            Text("This is only one line regardless of how long the sentence is")
                                .padding()
                                .lineLimit(1)
                            Text("Hello Swift - LargeTitle").font(.largeTitle).padding()
                            Text("Hello Swift - Title").font(.title).padding()
                            Text("Hello Swift - Headline").font(.headline).padding()
                            Text("Hello Swift - SubHeadline").font(.subheadline).padding()
                            Text("Hello Swift - body").font(.body).padding()
                    }
                    Group {
                            Text("Font Weight - Ultralight").fontWeight(.ultraLight).padding()
                            Text("Font Weight - Thin").fontWeight(.thin).padding()
                            Text("Font Weight - light").fontWeight(.light).padding()
                            Text("Font Weight - Regular").fontWeight(.regular).padding()
                    }
            }.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering why ScrollView couldn't have more than 10 views, the error I had was a compiler error `extra arguments at positions #11, #12, #13 in cal`, just to make this discoverable on Google. Thanks for the solution!